# How to scale text using Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

I came to know about Raphael.js recently and I was trying to do some hands on.
I would like to scale a text but it is not working.
After searching a lot in Google I have not find any idea.

Code is:

```
var paper = Raphael("paper1", 1000,1000);

var txt = paper.text(20,50,"Hello World").attr({
"font-family":"Arial","font-size":"30px", "font-weight": "normal", 
fill: "#000000", stroke:"black", "stroke-width": "0px",
"text-anchor" : "start" , "font-style": "normal"});
```

flip is working by txt.scale(-1,1)
but txt.scale(2,1) is not scaling the text.

Is there a way to scale a text?

Note: Font size of the text needs to remain same i.e 30px in my case.

Answer (score 5):

> **Is there a way to scale a text?**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vpGyL/987/)**

I checked and it works like a charm

```
var r = Raphael('test');

var t = r.text(200, 100, "I am a text").attr({fill:'red', 'font-size':30});

$('#zoomin').click(function() {
    t.scale(2);
});

$('#zoomout').click(function() {
    t.scale(.5);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much  A.S. Roma for your response and demo. But actually font size of the text is changing here.

Comment: Gourab, I think your question might not have been phrased very clearly -- A.S. has done exactly what I would have done, on the assumption that scaling implies a change in the apparent size of the font.  Your self answer below doesn't really clarify what you were attempting to do.

Comment: I had a note section with my question "Note: Font size of the text needs to remain same i.e 30px in my case."

Comment: Actually my question was to scale a text but font size needs to remain same and after some searching I came to know it is not possible with text. To scale a text without changing the font is possible after converting the text into image. Anyway I am very new in this so I could have done some mistake pls don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

If we scale the text only then font size shall be changed.
We need to convert the text into an image and the we need to scale it.
To do that I have used a hidden canvas.

Following code works for me.

```
<canvas id='textCanvas' style="display:none"></canvas>

<script>
  var paper = Raphael("paper1", 1000,1000);
  var img =  paper.image(getTxtImg("Hello World","italic","bold","15px","arial",
                                       "#000000",130,35),20,28,300,80)

  img.scale(2,1)  //Double in width
  img.scale(.5,1)  //Half  in width

function getTxtImg(txt,style,weight,fontsize,fontfamily,color,w,h)
{
  var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d');
  tCtx.canvas.width = w;
  tCtx.canvas.height = h    ;
  var fontstr = "" + style + " " + weight + " " + fontsize + " " + fontfamily + " ";
  tCtx.font = fontstr
  tCtx.fillStyle  = color
  tCtx.fillText(txt, 0, h);
  return tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
}
</script>
```